# mocking nested function is giving NPE

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

Hi I am getting Null Pointer Exception while trying to write unit test cases
Here is the class detail:

```
public CreateDraftCampaignResponse createDraftCampaign(CreateDraftCampaignRequest request) throws InvalidInputsException,
        DependencyException, UnauthorizedException {
    CreateDraftCampaignResponse draftCampaignResponse = null;

    try {
        DraftCampaignDetails createdDraft = draftCampaignI.createDraftCampaign(ConvertionUtil
                .getDraftCampaignDetailsfromCreateDraftRequest(request));
        draftCampaignResponse = new CreateDraftCampaignResponse();
        draftCampaignResponse.setDraftCampaignId(createdDraft.getDraftId());       
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Create Draft Campaign Exception", e);
        throw e;
    }
    return draftCampaignResponse;
}
```

This is the ConvertionUtil class:

```
 public static DraftCampaignDetails getDraftCampaignDetailsfromCreateDraftRequest(CreateDraftCampaignRequest request) {

    DraftCampaignDetails draftCampaign = new DraftCampaignDetails();

    DraftCampaignDetailsBase draftCampaignDetailsBase = request
            .getDraftCampaignDetailsBase(); (This is giving exception)
    draftCampaign.setCampaignBudget(draftCampaignDetailsBase
            .getCampaignBudget());
    draftCampaign.setCampaignName(draftCampaignDetailsBase
            .getCampaignName());
    draftCampaign.setDraftCampaignState(draftCampaignDetailsBase
            .getDraftCampaignState());

    draftCampaign.setCreatedUser(request.getUser());

    draftCampaign.setObfuscatedEntityId(request.getObfuscatedEntityId());
    draftCampaign.setCampaignInfo(request.getCampaignInfo());

    return draftCampaign;
}
```

Thsi is what I tried:

```
 @Test
 public void createDraft_newDraft() {
     DraftCampaignActivity draftContoller = new DraftCampaignActivity();

     CreateDraftCampaignRequest request = createRequest();
     DraftCampaignDetails details = buildDraftDetails();
     if(draftCampaignI == null){
         System.out.println("sccdscscd");
     }
     //ConvertionUtil action1 = PowerMockito.mock(ConvertionUtil.class);
     //PowerMockito.when(action1.getDraftCampaignDetailsfromCreateDraftRequest(request)).thenReturn(details);
     when(util.getDraftCampaignDetailsfromCreateDraftRequest(request)).thenReturn(details);
     when(draftCampaignI.createDraftCampaign(details)).thenReturn(details);




     CreateDraftCampaignResponse response = new CreateDraftCampaignResponse();
     draftContoller.createDraftCampaign(request);
     response.setDraftCampaignId(details.getDraftId());  
     Assert.assertEquals(response.getDraftCampaignId(),"ww");



 }
```

I am getting NPE. I am a novice in Mockito and other framework. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you try to mock a `static` method and you don't do it properly such that it calls the real method which leads to this NPE in your case.

To mock a `static` method using `Powermock`, you need to:

1. Use the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` annotation at the class-level of the test case.
2. Use the `@PrepareForTest(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class)` annotation at the class-level of the test case.
3. Use `PowerMock.mockStatic(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class)` to mock all methods of this class.

So in your case, you should have something like:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyTestClass {
    @Test
    @PrepareForTest(ConvertionUtil.class)
    public void createDraft_newDraft() {
        ...
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ConvertionUtil.class);
        PowerMockito.when(
            ConvertionUtil.getDraftCampaignDetailsfromCreateDraftRequest(request)
        ).thenReturn(details);
        ...
    }
```

More details about [How to mock a static method with Powermock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#mocking-static-method).

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for getting back. It is like midnight and I am breaking my head on this. I have mocked the static method. But it is giving new error now. Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554844/error-in-mocking-nested-calls for my new question. Please help so that I can have some good night sleep!!

Comment: replace the lines of your other question with what I propose here starting from `PowerMockito.mockStatic(...`

Comment: I'm missing the important advice that you should not use static methods since they make key featurs of OOP impossible, eg: polymorphism.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I would even add that static methods make your code harder to test and maintain as we can see here