# error in mocking nested calls

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have a simple line of Code:

```
 DraftCampaignDetails createdDraft = draftCampaignI.createDraftCampaign(ConvertionUtil
                .getDraftCampaignDetailsfromCreateDraftRequest(request));
```

I am trying to mock it like this:

```
 ConvertionUtil action1 = PowerMockito.mock(ConvertionUtil.class);
     when(action1.getDraftCampaignDetailsfromCreateDraftRequest(request)).thenReturn(details);

     when(draftCampaignI.createDraftCampaign(details)).thenReturn(details);
```

But I am getting this error:

```
 when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
```

Adding entire test class for more clarity:

```
public class DraftCampaignActivityTest {
@Mock 
IDraftCampaign draftCampaignI;

/*  @Mock 
ConvertionUtil util;*/

@Before
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public void setup()
    {
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

 @Test

 public void createDraft_newDraft() {
     DraftCampaignActivity draftContoller = new DraftCampaignActivity();

     CreateDraftCampaignRequest request = createRequest();
     DraftCampaignDetails details = buildDraftDetails();
     if(draftCampaignI != null){
         System.out.println("sccdscscd");
     }
    /* 
     if(util != null) {
         System.out.println("wewewew");
     }*/
    /// ConvertionUtil action1 = PowerMockito.mock(ConvertionUtil.class);
     PowerMockito.mockStatic(ConvertionUtil.class);
     PowerMockito.when(
                ConvertionUtil.getDraftCampaignDetailsfromCreateDraftRequest(request)
            ).thenReturn(details);

     when(draftCampaignI.createDraftCampaign(details)).thenReturn(details);
    // when(util.getDraftCampaignDetailsfromCreateDraftRequest(request)).thenReturn(details);




     CreateDraftCampaignResponse response = new CreateDraftCampaignResponse();
     draftContoller.createDraftCampaign(request);
     response.setDraftCampaignId(details.getDraftId());  
     Assert.assertEquals(response.getDraftCampaignId(),"ww");



 }

 private DraftCampaignDetails buildDraftDetails() {
     DraftCampaignDetails details = new DraftCampaignDetails();
     details.setDraftId("ww");
     return details;
 }

 private CreateDraftCampaignRequest createRequest() {
     CreateDraftCampaignRequest request = new CreateDraftCampaignRequest();
     request.setCampaignInfo("campaignInfo");
     request.setMarketplaceId("adadedaedaed");

     DraftCampaignDetailsBase base = new DraftCampaignDetailsBase();
     Money money = new Money();
     money.setCurrencyCode("USD");
     money.setMillicents(10L);
     base.setCampaignBudget(money);
     base.setCampaignName("name");
     base.setDraftCampaignState("DRAFT");
     request.setDraftCampaignDetailsBase(base);
     return request;

     //request
 }
```

I am new to Mockito and Powermock. please help! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `draftCampaignI` mocked?

Comment: Don't you want `when(draftCampaingnI.createDraftCampaign......` to return `action1` instead of `details`?

Comment: No @malka. createDraftCampaign takes the details object formed with ConvertionUtil and it returns the details object. More details can be seen here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554497/mocking-nested-function-is-giving-npe please help!

Comment: You need to add `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest(ConvertionUtil.class)` as shown in the other question

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. You have been very helpful. I have added all those. My bad. Now I am getting NPE in  draftCampaignI.createDraftCampaign(ConvertionUtil
                .getDraftCampaignDetailsfromCreateDraftRequest(request));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work `draftCampaignI` must be injected into `draftContoller`, to do so you need to declare `draftContoller` as a field of your test class annotated with `@InjectMocks`, no need to create the instance of `DraftCampaignActivity` explicitly anymore, leave it to Mockito, as next:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class DraftCampaignActivityTest {

    @Mock
    IDraftCampaign draftCampaignI;

    @InjectMocks
    DraftCampaignActivity draftContoller;

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest(ConvertionUtil.class)
    public void createDraft_newDraft() {
        CreateDraftCampaignRequest request = new CreateDraftCampaignRequest();
        DraftCampaignDetails details = new DraftCampaignDetails();

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ConvertionUtil.class);
        PowerMockito.when(
            ConvertionUtil.getDraftCampaignDetailsfromCreateDraftRequest(request)
        ).thenReturn(details);

        when(draftCampaignI.createDraftCampaign(details)).thenReturn(details);

        draftContoller.createDraftCampaign(request);
    }
}
```

Assuming that the class `DraftCampaignActivity` is of type:

```
public class DraftCampaignActivity {
    ...
    private IDraftCampaign draftCampaignI;
    ...
}
```

More details about the annotation [`InjectMocks`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.5.5/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html).

**NB:** As we use `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`, we have no need to call  `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` explicitly as it will be done internally such that the method `setup` is useless and can be removed.

Comment: I added the entire unit test class. Please have a look. draftCampaignI is a mock.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. Let me check

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. But it seems to have the same problem. The same exception is coming at Line "PowerMockito.when(
                ConvertionUtil.getDraftCampaignDetailsfromCreateDraftRequest(request)
            ).thenReturn(details);"

Comment: The exception is when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'. after making the above changes

Comment: Can you please send the import once? Sometimes, may be due to improper imports it happens!

Comment: Sure Nicolas. Let me test.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. Seems like some import issues. At least, I can get 3-4 hours of sleep now. All beacuse of you. Thanks Man!